# How do I remove the grey ring around a line?

Tags: html, css

[image: grey ring]

There is a grey ring around my line and I was wondering how I would remove it. I think it happens when I set a border-radius.

Comment: border:none ? ...

Comment: Everything we suggest will be a GUESS unless you post your relevant HTML / CSS  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

You would use CSS and it would be:

```
lineclass{
  border: none;
}
```

lineclass would be the "class" of your line

```
<line class="lineclass"></line>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm really not sure what you're looking for, but this could help.

`style="border: 1px solid transparent;"`